# Unable to Insert data from DropDownListFor to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using Dictionary to populate data into DropDownListFor. Now the problem is I am unable to fetch key on onchange event of DropDownListFor.
What I want is to select Schema on behalf of select client's KEY.

Controller:=

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    DataComponents dcomponents = new Models.DataComponents();
    //Getting Data From Database to Dictionary 
    dcomponents.clientName = getdata.Clients();
    dcomponents.schemaName = getdata.Schemas();
    return View(dcomponents);
}
public ActionResult Change(DataComponents dcomponents)
{
    //Select data on behalf of Client ID
    dcomponents.clientName = getdata.Clients();
    dcomponents.schemaName = getdata.Schemas(dcomponents.selectedClient);            
    return View("Index",dcomponents);
}
```

Model =>

```
public class DataComponents
{
    public Dictionary<int,string> clientName { get; set; }
    public int selectedClient { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, string> schemaName { get; set; }
    public int selectedSchema { get; set; }
}
```

View =>

```
<td>
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedClient,new SelectList(Model.clientName,"key","Value",Model.selectedClient), "Select Client", new { onchange = "document.location.href = '/Home/Change';" })
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedSchema, new SelectList(Model.schemaName, "key", "Value", Model.selectedClient), "Select Schema", new { onchange = "document.location.href = '/Home/Change';" }))
</td>
```

Comment: Your lower case Key in your view could be your only issue.

Example of Dictionary to SelectList: new SelectList(dict.OrderBy(x => x.Value), "Key", "Value", selectedValue);

Comment: Still not Working.

Comment: I don't know if your on change will work at all. You aren't submitting a form or sending any kind of body to the redirect. You are just doing a GET to /Home/Change.

try wrapping the drowpdowns in a form and using the onchange to submit the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the data to the server. Either through a post, or through query strings. I've model things as a post.

You can see I wrapped the View information in a Form, and changed the event to submit the form on change.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    DataComponents dcomponents = new Models.DataComponents();
    //Getting Data From Database to Dictionary 
    dcomponents.clientName = getdata.Clients();
    dcomponents.schemaName = getdata.Schemas();
    return View(dcomponents);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Change(DataComponents dcomponents)
{
    //Select data on behalf of Client ID
    dcomponents.clientName = getdata.Clients();
    dcomponents.schemaName = getdata.Schemas(dcomponents.selectedClient);            
    return View("Index",dcomponents);
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Change", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedClient,new SelectList(Model.clientName,"key","Value",Model.selectedClient), "Select Client", new { "this.form.submit();" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedSchema, new SelectList(Model.schemaName, "key", "Value", Model.selectedClient), "Select Schema", new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" }))
    </td>
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dan for your help.